# Create directories in Amazon S3 using python, boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I know S3 buckets not really have directories because the storage is flat. But it is possible to create directories programmaticaly with python/boto3, but I don't know how. I saw this on a documentary :

*"Although S3 storage is flat: buckets contain keys, S3 lets you impose a directory tree structure on your bucket by using a delimiter in your keys.
For example, if you name a key ‘a/b/f’, and use ‘/’ as the delimiter, then S3 will consider that ‘a’ is a directory, ‘b’ is a sub-directory of ‘a’, and ‘f’ is a file in ‘b’."*

I can create just files in the a S3 Bucket by :

```
    self.client.put_object(Bucket=bucketname,Key=filename)
```

but I don't know how to create a directory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just a little modification in key name is required. `self.client.put_object(Bucket=bucketname,Key=filename)`

this should be changed to

`self.client.put_object(Bucket=bucketname,Key=directoryname/filename)`

Thats all.

Answer (score 16):

If you read the API documentation You should be able to do this.

```
import boto3 
s3 = boto3.client("s3") 
BucketName = "mybucket"
myfilename = "myfile.dat"
KeyFileName = "/a/b/c/d/{fname}".format(fname=myfilename) 
with open(myfilename) as f : 
  object_data = f.read()
  client.put_object(Body=object_data, Bucket=BucketName, Key=KeyFileName)
```

Honestly, it is not a "real directory", but preformat string structure for organisation.

Answer (score 9):

Adding forward slash `/` to the end of key name, to create directory didn't work for me:

```py
client.put_object(Bucket="foo-bucket", Key="test-folder/")
```

You have to supply `Body` parameter in order to create directory:

```py
client.put_object(Bucket='foo-bucket',Body='', Key='test-folder/')
```

Source: [ryantuck in boto3 issue](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/377#issuecomment-219535645)

Comment: The Body key should be a bytes object in Python 3.x, so I'd recommend Body=b'' (with the leading b).